# What is the interpretation of the following version of the first law: $\sum p_i E_i = \sum p_i dE_i + \sum E_i dp_i $

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

The first law of thermodynamics can be written as:

$$ U= <E> = \sum p_i E_i = \sum p_i dE_i + \sum  E_i dp_i $$
$$ U= E = \delta Q + \delta W $$

Where

$$\delta W = \sum_{i=1}^N p_i\,dE_i$$
$$\delta Q = \sum_{i=1}^N E_i\,dp_i$$

Looking at: $ U = \sum p_i E_i $ it is clear that the internal energy is the expected value of the energies.

However what does $\sum_{i=1}^N p_i\,dE_i$ relate to work, it means the expected change in energy? And for heat it is the expected change in 'probability' $p_i$?

Comment: The third equality in the first line of your question does not make sense. The quantity on the LHS is finite and the quantities on the RHS are infinitesimal.

Comment: See for example the box [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(statistical_thermodynamics)#Gibbs_entropy_formula).

Answer (score 3):

> The first law of thermodynamics can be written as:
>
> $$ U= <E> = \sum p_i E_i = \sum p_i dE_i + \sum  E_i dp_i $$

Not sure what this is, but it is definitely not the first law of thermodynamics. For example, you have finite quantities like $U$ on the LHS and you have infinitesimal quantities like $dE_i$ on the RHS. You can't equate finite and infinitesimal things.

> $$ U= E = \delta Q + \delta W $$

This *is* the first law of thermodynamics in terms of the work done *on* the system $\delta W$.

> Looking at: $ U = \sum p_i E_i $ it is clear that the internal energy is the expected value of the energies.

And furthermore $dU= \sum_i d(p_i E_i)$, which might be what you want to have on the LHS of your equation quoted above.

> However what does $\sum_{i=1}^N p_i\,dE_i$ relate to work, it means the expected change in energy?

From the [Wikipedia entry on Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(statistical_thermodynamics)#Gibbs_entropy_formula) (specifically, the box labelled "Entropy changes for systems in a canonical state"), we read that: "If the changes are sufficiently slow, so that the system remains in the same microscopic state, but the state slowly (and reversibly) changes, **then $\sum_i dE_i p_i$ is the expectation value of the work done **on** the system through this reversible process**..." (Emphasis added).

You can see this more explicitly by working the steps backwards in the wikipedia article box. Namely (for sufficiently slow changes):
$$
dW = \sum_i dE_i p_i
$$
$$
=\sum_i d(E_i p_i) - E_i dp_i
$$
$$
=dU - \sum_i dp_i(E_i + T\ln(Z))
$$
(since $T\ln(Z)\sum_i dp_i = 0$)
$$
=dU + \sum_i dp_i(T\ln(p_i))\;.
$$
(for the canonical ensemble, and where I have chosen units such that the Boltzmann constant is 1.)
$$
=dU + T\sum_i d(p_i\ln(p_i))
$$
(since $\sum_i dp_i = 0$)
$$
=dU - TdS = dU - dQ\;,
$$
which is the infinitesimal form of the first law of thermodynamics:
$$
dW = dU - dQ
$$

Answer (score 1):

As noted elsewhere, you need an integral or a derivative operator somewhere in your First Law formulation to avoid equating finite and infinitesimal quantities.

I quote from McQuarrie's *Statistical Mechanics*:

*"...we used the fact that
the average work done on a system was $P_j \,dE_j$. We do work, then, by changing the energies slightly, but keeping the population of these states fixed (the $P_j$'s do not change). A molecular interpretation of thermodynamic work, then, is a change in the quantum mechanical energy states of the system, keeping the population over them fixed. That a molecular interpretation of the absorption of heat is the inverse of this can be seen from $$d\bar{E} = \sum_j E_j \,dP_j + \sum_j P_j\,dE_j =\delta q_\text{rev}-\delta w_\text{rev}.$$
Thus when a small quantity of heat is absorbed from the surroundings, the energy
states of the system do not change ($N$ and $V$ are fixed), but the population of these states does. "*

Is this the type of interpretation you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First law of thermodynamics can be extrapolated from an ideal gas law, which states that internal energy of gas is :
$$ pV = nRT = 2/3U = U' $$

Differentiating both sides:

$$ dU' = d(pV) $$

Using [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) :

$$ dU' = Vdp + pdV $$

Noticing that second term is work done by gas, when it expands, namely $dW=-pdV$ :

$$ dU' = Vdp - dW $$

When enthalpy of gas does not change, then $|Vdp|=|TdS|=dQ$, so we arrive at :
$$ dU' = dQ-dW $$

It's not an exact explanation of your question, but may give some ideas which will put you on the right path.
Here's a good book about [theory of heat](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Epowers/ame.20231/clausius1879.pdf) which you can check more.